# How to fix missing and uneven boxes in memorama table

Tags: python, list

I am building a 6x6 memorama of number emojis and how they are written in English. The table has labeled rows and columns from 0-5. Row 0 has 6 values as it should but they are not evenly spaced, row 1 has only 5 instead of 6 values and is not spaced out, same with row 2 but with only 4 values, then with row 3, 4 and 5 but each with 5 values.
My aim is to fill out boxes in the 6x6 evenly, so that every number is repeated once (there is 18 numbers 1-18). How can I achieve this?

- Here is the function for the numbering of rows and columns:

```
def despliega_tablero(opcion, matriz, r1 = None, c1 = None, r2 = None, c2 = None):
    if opcion == 1:
        print (matriz)
    else:
        print("        0       |        1       |        2       |        3       |        4       |        5       |")
        print("--------------" * len (matriz))
        num_renglon = 0
        for renglon in matriz:
            print(num_renglon, "|", end="")
            num_renglon = num_renglon + 1

            for elemento in renglon:
                print (f' {elemento}'.center (5), end="")
                print("|", end="")
            print('\n'+ "---------------" * len (renglon))
```

- Here is the function of the things that should fill up the table evenly 6x6

```
def pares( ):
    lista = []
    #numbers, all the way from 1 to 18
    pares = """\u0031\u20E3 - one\n\u0032\u20E3 - two\n\u0033\u20E3 - three\n\u0034\u20E3 - four\n\u0035\u20E3 - five\n\u0036\u20E3 - six\n
\u0037\u20E3 - seven\n\u0038\u20E3 - eight\n\u0039\u20E3 - nine\n\u0031\u20E3\u0030\u20E3 - ten\n\u0031\u20E3\u0031\u20E3 - eleven
\n\u0031\u20E3\u0032\u20E3 - twelve\n\u0031\u20E3\u0033\u20E3 - thirteen\n\u0031\u20E3\u0034\u20E3 - fourteen\n\u0031\u20E3\u0035\u20E3 - fifteen
\n\u0031\u20E3\u0036\u20E3 - sixteen\n\u0031\u20E3\u0037\u20E3 - seventeen\n\u0031\u20E3\u0038\u20E3 - eighteen
"""
    lista = pares.split("\n")
    lista = lista * 2
    print(lista)
    print(len(lista))
    return lista
```

The resulting table looks something like this, but unevenly spaced (meaning the text doesn't fall so nicely into the boxes):

```
        0       |        1       |        2       |        3       |        4       |        5       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 | 1⃣ - one| 2⃣ - two| 3⃣ - three| 4⃣ - four| 5⃣ - five| 6⃣ - six|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |     | 7⃣ - seven| 8⃣ - eight| 9⃣ - nine| 1⃣0⃣ - ten| 1⃣1⃣ - eleven|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 |     | 1⃣2⃣ - twelve| 1⃣3⃣ - thirteen| 1⃣4⃣ - fourteen| 1⃣5⃣ - fifteen|     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 | 1⃣6⃣ - sixteen| 1⃣7⃣ - seventeen| 1⃣8⃣ - eighteen|     | 1⃣ - one| 2⃣ - two|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 | 3⃣ - three| 4⃣ - four| 5⃣ - five| 6⃣ - six|     | 7⃣ - seven|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 | 8⃣ - eight| 9⃣ - nine| 1⃣0⃣ - ten| 1⃣1⃣ - eleven|     | 1⃣2⃣ - twelve|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When really, it should simply fill up every box with a number from 1 to 18 so that all numbers are repeated once and all 36 boxes are filled up.

I tried adding the numbers manually with prints.

Comment: Side note: are you sure "mammogram" is the right term here?

Comment: changed it, sorry got confused in translation from Spanish to English my bad